# Dynamics CRM Dashboard views and charts

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a challenge to create a structure to modify chart based on a view selected (On a dashboard).

ex: When an user click on view 1 modify to chart 1 and also, when User clicks on view 2 modify to chart 2.

Are there some way to achieve this with some development? Someone has one solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to achieve mutually linked Dashboard components. This is not possible to link the individual components by OOB or even in supported customizations/code.

Rather you can configure a Dashboard component with Chart & Enable both the View Selector + Chart Selector. This way you have control to show the necessary views/charts & users can choose the from the available list to visualize.

[image]

[Read more](https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/aishev/e-book-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-personal-dashboard)